# QR code scanning with Zxing library differs a lot between different phones

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

We have integrated `me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing` into our app and use the `ZXingScannerView` to scan QR-codes on some physical devices. Our issue is that the performance is extremely different on different phones. Some of them register the QR-code immediately while some might get it after a while and some never registers them.

I'm guessing the different specifics of the actual camera is the underlying cause.
Many phones which won't scan the QR-code will however scan the code fine if you use the native camera App. My guess is that we don't get auto-focus and such when we import the camera into the `ZXingScannerView` which makes the QR-code more blurry and hard to detect.

Has anyone else had this issue and what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: `me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing` seems to be a very old fork of the main project that has been archived and no longer under development, may be try something more up to date?

Comment: I sort of did that. I went to `1.9.13` and started setting `setAutoFocus(true)` and `setAspectTolerance(0.5f)` and now all my misbehaving phones started working. The actual preview looks pretty skewed on some of them but at least it works!

Comment: No, the fork is old, this version of the library has not been touched in about 4 years and has been archived because it is no longer maintained and the main zxing is on version 3.5.1 I suggest you get another version for a different location. The main project is at https://github.com/zxing/zxing